# Packaging Error, trying to make iPhone app in Titanium

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm having problems trying to package my Appcelerator Titanium app.

It builds correctly, and I can run it on my iPod Touch.

When I try to Package for distribution in the App Store I get the following errors in build.log:

```
Build details:

   timestamp=12/16/10 16:25
   version=1.5.1
   githash=16bbb92


Script arguments:
   /Users/wfm2/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py
   distribute
   "4.2"
   "/Users/wfm2/Documents/Nick Hutton/SynthBasics1"
   net.macdonaldsoftware.synthbasics1
   "SynthBasics1"
   <null>
   "William Macdonald"
   "/Users/wfm2/Documents/Nick Hutton/SynthBasics1"
   iphone

Building from: /Users/wfm2/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone
Platform: Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386

Xcode path is: /Developer


Exception detected in script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wfm2/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py", line 599, in main
    provisioning_profile = read_provisioning_profile(pp,o)
  File "/Users/wfm2/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.5.1/iphone/builder.py", line 212, in read_provisioning_profile
    f = open(f,'rb').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/Users/wfm2/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/<null>.mobileprovision'
```

Comment: Please ignore this question, problem between chair and keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not appear that you have your mobile provisioning profile configured properly; based on the last line of the output you provided.

you need to goto developer.apple.com and download your provisioning profile